# Generate Series of month and years

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, generate-series

How do I generate a series of month and year dates which I can use as a parameter to pass to other data tables.

For example, I am currently using:

```
MonthYearSelector = GENERATESERIES(DATE(2019,1,1), DATE(2019,12,1),30)
```

However, this generates the following dates:

```
01 January 2019
31 January 2019
02 March 2019
...
```

What I want is the following list:
01 January 2019
01 February 2019
01 March 2019
....

```
MonthYearSelector = GENERATESERIES(DATE(2019,1,1), DATE(2019,12,1),30)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
MonthYearSelector = 
VAR Years = SELECTCOLUMNS( {2018, 2019}, "Year", [Value] )
VAR Months = SELECTCOLUMNS( GENERATESERIES(1, 12, 1), "Month", [Value] )
RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CROSSJOIN( Years, Months ),
    "Date", DATE( [Year], [Month], 1 )
)
```

In the above, I use `SELECTCOLUMNS` just to rename the default `Value` column name.

[image: Calendar Table]

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me. I am creating this field as a parameter, if that makes any difference

Comment: Can you clarify how it's not working? Are you getting an error message? Are you getting unexpected results?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.. It's basically give you start of the month & End of the Month...  your choice to use..

```
Start of Month Dates = 
  GENERATE (
    GENERATESERIES(1,48),
    VAR inc = [Value]
  RETURN ROW (
    "date", DATE(2017,inc,1),
    "Month End",EOMONTH(DATE(2017,inc,1),0)
    )
  )
```

[Check this for details](https://powerbi.tips/2017/12/start-of-month-dax-calendar/)